# ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'Q'

Tags: python, pandas, logistic-regression, one-hot-encoding

I am new to programming and I was working with the titanic dataset from Kaggle. I have been trying to build the Logistic Regression model after performing one-hot encoding. But I keep getting the error. I think the error is caused due to the dummy variable. Below is my code.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib as plt
import seaborn as sns

#Loading data
df=pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\Downloads\train.csv")

#Deleting unwanted columns
df.drop(["PassengerId","Name","Cabin","Ticket"],axis=1,inplace=True)

#COunt of Missing values in each column
print(df.isnull().sum())

#Deleting rows with missing values based on column name
df.dropna(subset=['Embarked','Age'],inplace=True)
print(df.isnull().sum())

#One hot encoding for categorical variables
#Creating dummy variables for Sex column
dummies = pd.get_dummies(df.Sex)
dummies2=pd.get_dummies(df.Embarked)

#Appending the dummies dataframe with original dataframe
new_df= pd.concat([df,dummies,dummies2],axis='columns')

print(type(new_df))
#print(new_df.head(10))

#Drop the original sex,Embarked column and one of the dummy column for bth variables
new_df.drop(['Sex','Embarked'],axis='columns',inplace=True)
print(new_df.head(10))

new_df.info()

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix,accuracy_score

x = df.drop('Survived', axis=1)
y = df['Survived']

logmodel = LogisticRegression()

logmodel.fit(x, y)
```

Comment: where exactly is this error happening? Also please edit your code to include a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: I think **x** and **y** should be: `x =new_df.drop('Survived', axis=1)` and `y = new_df['Survived']` by changing `df` to `new_df`. Is this the case?

Comment: Could you point out at what line is the error coming ?

Comment: Thanks. actually that was the mistake. @Anwarvic  But now even though the model works, I get a few warning like "ConvergenceWarning: lbfgs failed to converge (status=1):
STOP: TOTAL NO. of ITERATIONS REACHED LIMIT."   What could this be?

Comment: @JohnPaul, try increasing the number of iterations like so: `logmodel = LogisticRegression(max_iter=1000)`

Comment: @JohnPaul Did it work??

Comment: @Anwarvic, Yes it did. Thanks a bunch

Comment: @JohnPaul, Glad I could help. I have added the answer as it may be helpful for other people.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As we discussed in the comments, here is the solution:

First, you need to modify your `x` and `y` variables to use `new_df` instead of `df` just like so:

```
x = new_df.drop('Survived', axis=1)
y = new_df['Survived']
```

Then, you need to increase the iteration of your Logistic Regression Model like so:

```
logmodel = LogisticRegression(max_iter=1000)
```